# Types of setter arguments not showing in Sphinx documentation

Tags: python, documentation, python-sphinx, type-hinting, read-the-docs

I can't figure out how to get the type hints to appear in the Sphinx generated documentation from setters arguments.

I have a Python class with an attribute called batches and I've got docstrings in the property and type hinting in the setter argument (int). Below is the minimal example, but [here](https://github.com/shimwell/openmc/blob/moving_docstrings_to_setters/openmc/settings.py) is the full version

```
class Settings:
    """Settings used"""

    def __init__(self):
        self._batches = None 

    @property
    def batches(self):
        """Number of batches to simulate"""
        return self._batches

    @batches.setter
    def batches(self, batches: int):
        self._batches = batches
```

I'm building documentation with sphinx and using the following command

```
sphinx-build -b html ./source/ ./build/html/
```

In the [conf.py](https://github.com/shimwell/openmc/blob/6c0ad123c4f5dc2435db603c393c15bcf080059d/docs/source/conf.py#L42) I have the "sphinx_autodoc_typehints" package before the napoleon package as suggested by the sphinx docs. I have also tried putting it after just to check :-)

In the [docs I am using :autosummary:](https://github.com/shimwell/openmc/blob/moving_docstrings_to_setters/docs/source/pythonapi/base.rst)

```
.. autosummary::
   :toctree: generated
   :nosignatures:
   :template: myclass.rst
```

The docs [are building](https://openmc--2016.org.readthedocs.build/en/2016/pythonapi/generated/openmc.Settings.html#openmc.Settings) but the type hints are not appearing:

[image: doc output]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A property made using the decorators is for all purposes the same as an attribute. It is not a function.  Sphinx honors this.  Actually, Sphinx only read the documentation for the `@property` method, not the `@property.setter` one at all.

In your case, specifying a type hint for the base property should be enough.

```
class Settings:

    @property
    def batches(self) -> int:
        """Number of batches to simulate"""
        return self._batches
```

In case your setter accepts other types (like floats, strings, etc) and manage to cast this input as an int internally, you can document that as prose in the base property, like so.

```
class Settings:

    @property
    def batches(self) -> int:
        """Number of batches to simulate

        When set with a non integer value, the value is coerced
        as an integer, or will raise a :exc:`TypeError` if this 
        fails.
        """
        return self._batches

    @batches.setter
    def batches(self, batches: Union[int,str]):
        self._batches = int(batches)
```

Comment: Thank you @abstrus this really helps, and thanks for adding the extended answer with the multiple types. This solution has now got the types appearing in readthedocs

Comment: Now I'm wondering if we can put ```-> Union[int,str]``` in the return type as it appears sphinx accepts it

Comment: @OpenMCWorkshop About the Union fr the "normal" property, this would tell your user that when they read the property the could receive one or the other.  In all honesty, to honor the principle of least surprise for APIs, if your setter implement type-casting semantics or any other complex API, you should probably not use getters and setters at all, but good old functions.